# Why is my PREPAREed statment giving the same value sha1 for all rows?

Tags: mysql

Dipping pinky into prepared sql.
MySQL 5.6.23  InnoDB
So far I have this

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @stmt;
select @stmt, @key1, @feed_id;
-- result is like this
-- stmt = "select sha1(concat('{',? ,'}',?)) sha1, id from mytable"
-- key1  = "'location=',Location,'term=',Term"
-- feed_id = 10
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @key1, @feed_id;
```

This gives me a result BUT the first column (sha1) is the same value for each result row.  That is not correct!

If I do the substitution myself and run the command I get what I expected (a different value for sha1 for each row)

This is an example statement that works as I expect

```
select sha1(concat('{','location=',Location,'term=',Term ,'}',1129)) sha1,
       id 
from My_table
```

Makes me think about volatile functions But that is not a thing in MySQL or is it?

I am using dynamic SQL because the key1 and the table names can both be calculated and I have many thousands to process.

anyone have an idea what is going on or some things to try?

Comment: Parameters can’t be expressions; you seem to just be looking to concatenate parts of a query together.

Comment: since the expression takes parms that I want to provide.  can you suggest a way to make it work?

Comment: Can you give an example of other values for @key1 that you would want to use

Comment: key1    comes from a select

Comment: `SELECT @key1 := GROUP_CONCAT(concat('\'',lower(fieldName),'=\',',fieldName)) 
 FROM field     where feed_id  = @feed_id and type = 'K' order by 1`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating my statement string with all the values and then issuing a PREPARE  then EXECUTE did not require any params.  It worked.   But I will need to RE PREPARE the statement for each execution.  That is sloppy but good enough for my needs.

The statement now looks like this:

```
SET @stmt2 = CONCAT("select sha1(concat('{',", @key1," ,'}',", @feed_id, ")) sha1, ts_id from ",@table_name);
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @stmt2;
EXECUTE stmt3;
```